# How can I integrate the Amadeus API with my Laravel web page?

Tags: php, laravel, soap, amadeus

I need integrate the Amadeus API in my Laravel web page, because I can't find how can integrate this, I have learned some documentation for work in PHP, in other cases work in Laravel but no necesary with Amadeus, but with SOAP, I need to do this integration, Could you help me? please!

Answer (score 1):

There is a PHP library to integrate the Amadeus Web Services SOAP interface in a PHP application. It sounds like what you need: https://github.com/amabnl/amadeus-ws-client/

Although this library doesn't provide any ready-made UI or any integration with Laravel, it is a composer package that can be included in any PHP composer-enabled projects easily. It does all the heavy lifting of session handling and creation, sending and receiving of SOAP messages.

I suggest you check it out, start with reading the Getting Started docs: https://github.com/amabnl/amadeus-ws-client/blob/master/docs/about-get-started.rst

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate SOAP with your laravel application, you can use this package: https://github.com/artisaninweb/laravel-soap and just follow Amadeus API documentation.